# How do I add or subtract parts of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, math

I've been trying to add the first integer in my array to the second, however all I keep getting is random letters. What do I do?

I've tried.

```
firstArray[1] = firstArray[1] + firstArray[0];
```

```
firstArray[1] = FirstArray[0];
```

This works fine but I can't seem to add or subtract the two numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

string firstArray = {0,0, '/', 0, 0, '/', 0, 0};
int main(){

  cout << firstArray <<endl;
  firstArray[1] = firstArray[0]; //this works
  cout << firstArray << endl;
  cout << firstArray <<endl;
  firstArray[1] = firstArray[0] + firstArray[1]; //this is the bit that doesn't work
    firstArray[1] = firstArray[1] + firstArray[0]; //neither does this

  cout << "thanks guys :)" <<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here: `cout << "thanks guys :) <<endl;` you missed closing double quotes

Comment: Woops, i justed added that though, it isn't in my original code.

Comment: Please post a compiling code snippet, otherwise it is hard to tell what is the issue. `tryAgain` is not defined in your code

Comment: how do i do that? i've fixed the second one, for the purposes of the question i changed the name to make more sense but forgot to replace all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector<int>` for an array of integers. I see that the code in the question uses `string`; this is incorrect - `string` is for strings of characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> firstArray = {3, 4, 42, 69};

int main(){

  std::cout << firstArray[0] << '\n';
  std::cout << firstArray[1] << '\n';
  firstArray[1] = firstArray[0]; //this works
  std::cout << firstArray[0] << '\n';
  std::cout << firstArray[1] << '\n';
  firstArray[1] = firstArray[0] + firstArray[1]; //this works
  std::cout << firstArray[0] << '\n';
  std::cout << firstArray[1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: How can i do that with a mix of integers and characters, as I need to receive input(a whole date) and add the two first digits.

Comment: Mixing integers and characters is another topic, which is significantly different. You might want to ask a separate question for that. Make sure you describe exactly what you are trying to do and why, and what went wrong. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you receive the input as a string you can convert the first 2 digits to integers and then add them up.

```
std::string str = "00/00/00";

int n1 = std::stoi(str.substr(0, 1));
int n2 = std::stoi(str.substr(1, 2));

int s = n1 + n2;

std::cout << s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Characters in C++ are internally represented as integers but those have range. I think the confusion for you is that if you write  integers in double quotes then you can't use that as integer rather you should think that it is a character.

However,If you want to work with integers then you need an array of integers and if you want the input as strings then you have to parse those strings to make them integers.

To do that you can use `stoi` to convert to integers and `stod` for converting them to double and both of these functions can be used by including `<string>` and the `namespace` `std`.